# Is this an appropriate way to define and use a Python exception?

Tags: python, exception

I just want to make sure I'm doing this in the proper "pythonic" way - I want to make sure I've defind - and am using - this exception class correctly.  Especially the eval(repr()) logic - it's mostly for cleanliness, I understand why you end up with quotes around the string repr() returns, but I don't like to log them.

```
class IPCClientError(Exception):
    """ General IPC Client Exception class """
    def __init__(self, value = "Unspecified error"):
        self.val = value + ", see IPC client log for details."

    def __str__(self):
        return eval(repr(self.val))
```

When I raise the exception, I use something like:

```
raise IPCClientError("Socket error")
```

And then the calling method will have something like this:

```
except IPCClientError, exc:
    self.log.error(str(exc))
    return ERROR
```

Comment: Yup Your doing it right, except you should re-raise the exception.

Comment: You're right, I should, maybe the next time I have an opportunity to do some refactoring :)

Comment: Why are you using `return eval(repr(self.val))` instead of just `return self.val`?

Comment: Don't put unnecessary spaces around your """docstring text""".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
eval(repr(self.val))
```

Eek, what are you trying to accomplish here? isn't `self.val` already supposed to be a string?

The way to avoid the quotes that `repr` attaches is not to use it in the first place.

If you're worried that the value passed to the constructor won't be a string, well - that will fail in the constructor (`unicode` quibbles notwithstanding) anyway and you'll just get a `TypeError` raised before your custom exception can be.

As for how you handle the exception, exception handling is kind of an art, and really not something that can be covered in this space...

Comment: Ah, just had a "duh" moment! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

(apart from the `eval` stuff already mentioned by others)

In your `except` statement, you should write `except IPCClientError as exc:` (notice the "as"), which is the newer, python 3 compatible way to do it. (the other syntax won't work anymore in python 3, the new one works in python 2.6 and higher)